# Finding source of volume in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a large Docker volume (300GB) that I want to get rid of. The problem is I can't figure out what's using it.

I've already run:

```bash
docker volume prune
docker system prune -a --volumes
```

and the volume is still there, which indicates something is using it.

Running `docker ps -a --filter volume=VOLUME_NAME` returns zero results.

How can I figure out what this volume is being used for?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Checking docker Container Id

```bash
docker inspect {docker container id}
```

and There will be JSON output, look at "Mounts" section to see if the volume you're trying to delete is mounted inside that container.

Answer (score 1):

> (...) which indicates something is using it

That statement was true until very recently indeed, but, has, now, changed.

As of Docker 23.0.0, the `docker volume prune` command consider all named volumes should be kept, regardless of their usage.

Here is the issue on their GitHub tracker discussing that matter: https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/4028

---

If this is your case, you can run either

```bash
docker volume prune --filter all=1
```

or, since 23.0.5

```bash
docker volume prune --all # or -a
```

---

Sources:

- https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/4028#issuecomment-1429538145
- https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/4028#issuecomment-1556165873